# Laravel 5.7 - How to use models & controllers in a custom PHP project?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel install, setup as a new CMS.

The frontend of the site is a pretty complex old website. The new CMS is going to take over a portion of it, but migrating everything to Laravel isn't an option.

I understand that I can use https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database to enable Eloquent and make database queries. However, what this doesn't include is the models I've already created as part of the CMS.

So on the same server I have:

- `/var/www/laravel-cms/`  <- Laravel based CMS
- `/var/www/website.com/`  <- Custom PHP Project

How can I use my models created in `laravel-cms` on `website.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping you from copying ( or perhaps simlinking) your legacy models into the /var/www/laravel-cms/app directory and then using namespaces to call those models from the the controller?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...
use App\Legacy-Models\Model1 as Example;

class ExampleController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $ex = new Example();
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create some method in your Laravel controller using the Laravel model. then call the function from website.com using Curl.